# Django Send-mail Error [Errno 10060]

Tags: django

I am trying to send email from my django application but unable to do so

```
# Running the shell

python manage.py shell
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Test','This is a test', 'saikat.dasgupta2006@gmail.com',
['erdasgupta@gmail.com])

error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
connected party didnot properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Updated settings.py file to include following
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'saikat.dasgupta2006@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'afchbhnaysjthdow' (application specific password)
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Any suggestions?? I am using Python 2.7 , Django 1.9 and running on Windows XP

Comment: There is no proxy set. When I run, the script hangs for sometime and gives the error

Answer (score 4):

```
import smtplib


def send_mail(from_addr, to_addr_list, subject, email_body):
    SMTP_SESSION = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    SMTP_SESSION.ehlo()
    SMTP_SESSION.starttls()
    SMTP_SESSION.login(settings.GMAIL_EMAIL, 'liomessi')

    headers = "\r\n".join(["from: " + 'My Test Mail',
                       "subject: " + subject,
                       "mime-version: 1.0",
                       "content-type: text/html"])
    # body_of_email can be plaintext or html!                    
    content = headers + "\r\n\r\n" + email_body
    SMTP_SESSION.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, content)

send_mail(from_addr = settings.GMAIL_EMAIL, to_addr_list =['abc@gmail.com'], subject = 'Welcome the site', email_body = 'Thanks for joining our site we are glad that you are here')
```

I am also using django to send mail by the following settings and able to send mail to the person. I think you need to specify the content-type and mime-version. Then you would be able to send the mail.

Comment: import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['saikat.dasgupta2006@gmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception , e:
   print "Error: unable to send email" + str(e)  - It Failed With Same Error

Comment: Saikat Dasgupta , google blocks the email sending request most of the time , Please make your email sending account less secure that might solve you problem. go to the link : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: @SaikatDasgupta If you are using SSL then please refer to this google documentation : https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Here is a simple code I have written. Please help me with how to get this working.         #!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['saikat.dasgupta2006@gmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception , e:
   print "Error: unable to send email" + str(e)

Comment: Hello Chitrank. Many thanks for suggesting on this. I got this working on my local network but I am facing issue while using my office network. Its again giving timeout error while in office network. Please help. Probably need to bypass proxy